# How to Determine Transaction Status and Implement Refunds with Cybersource API in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, payment, applepay, google-pay, cybersource

I am currently working on implementing a refund feature for Apple Pay and Google Pay transactions using **Cybersource** in **Node.js**. I am using the **"cybersource-rest-client"** package version **"^0.0.51"** for this purpose.

My goal is to determine the status of a transaction – whether it has been settled/batched or is still open – and then initiate the appropriate refund process based on this status.

During my exploration of the Cybersource API documentation, I have reviewed the following resources:

1. [Payment Reversal Process - Authorization Reversal](https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#payments_reversal_process-an-authorization-reversal)
2. [Cybersource Knowledgebase Article](https://support.cybersource.com/knowledgebase/knowledgearticle/?code=000001606)

I noticed a "status" column in the documentation but am uncertain about how to effectively use it to determine the transaction status using the "cybersource-rest-client" package in Node.js. Can someone provide guidance on how to retrieve the status of a transaction and which specific endpoint to call for open transactions versus settled/batched transactions?

Any insights, examples, or Node.js code snippets leveraging the "cybersource-rest-client" package would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance.